# Power shell and GitBash shows the different docker image in windows OS

Tags: docker, powershell, git-bash, minikube

Hi I have installed docker desktop on my Windows machine.

If I list the docker image using Powershell or Docker Desktop or Cmd I can see the some set of docker images.
I can view the same in Git bash. I am not able to view the docker image listed by Powershell. But I am able to view some different image.

What config I need to update to get the same docker images from PowerShell and GitBash

How can I use the minikube using the docker image from my local system.

Comment: You should show what you are running and the output you’re referencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to not mix up the Git for Windows bash shell, and the native Powershell.

The `%PATH%` might be different in a Powershell from Docker, and a bash shell from Git.

you can therefore follow "[Getting started with Docker and Kubernetes on Windows 10](https://learnk8s.io/installing-docker-kubernetes-windows)" from [Keith Mifsud](https://twitter.com/keithmifsud), using WSL2 or Hyper-V

[image: https://learnk8s.io/a/910680214fe92f195831d8f128c5a7f3.svg]

See also "[Install Minikube in Windows 10 via Docker Desktop 2021 Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83CYLbejUTU)"